# Get instance of org.apache.maven.plugin.descriptor.PluginDescriptor by parsing pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

Is is possible to get instance of org.apache.maven.plugin.descriptor.PluginDescriptor from just pom.xml file using java application?

Comment: Before posting your question, please show us what have you done to implement it.

Comment: @Krishna, nothing as such. I'm trying to execute the [maven plugin](https://github.com/phoenixnap/springmvc-raml-plugin) from my gradle project and the class 'SpringMvcEndpointGeneratorMojo' class which get executed from this maven plugin needs PluginDescription instance, hence trying to found workaround wherein I can configure instance of PluginDescription from java application by parsing a pom.xml file.